# PDF/A compliance with word/pdf-t-maker/ghostscript

Tags: pdf, ms-word, ghostscript, pdfa

I am using PDF-T-Maker to convert a  word file to pdf/a. I had to go this route to embed some fonts rather than bitmap them in. A text only document shows up with the blue banner indicating PDF/A on Adobe reader. But, when I include a TOC in the word file, the blue banner doesnt show up.
I am using Ghostscript 9.07 as the distiller. When I tried gswin64 to convert pdf to pdf/a without the -nopause switch, I got a "annotation set to non-printing" warning but even with the -sPDFAcompatibility switch set to 1, I dont get a PDF/A compliant file. I read that the PDFA_def.ps might need to be modified to my environment. Wondering if that is the issue or if there is some other fix. i am using Win7.

Thanks a bunch!

PDFA_def.ps

```
%!
% This is a sample prefix file for creating a PDF/A document.
% Feel free to modify entries marked with "Customize".

% This assumes an ICC profile to reside in the file (ISO Coated sb.icc),
% unless the user modifies the corresponding line below.

% Define entries in the document Info dictionary :

/ICCProfile (ISO Coated sb.icc)   % Customize.
def

[ /Title (Title)                  % Customize.
  /DOCINFO pdfmark

% Define an ICC profile :

[/_objdef {icc_PDFA} /type /stream /OBJ pdfmark
[{icc_PDFA} <</N systemdict /ProcessColorModel get /DeviceGray eq {1} {4} ifelse >> /PUT pdfmark
[{icc_PDFA} ICCProfile (r) file /PUT pdfmark

% Define the output intent dictionary :

[/_objdef {OutputIntent_PDFA} /type /dict /OBJ pdfmark
[{OutputIntent_PDFA} <<
  /Type /OutputIntent             % Must be so (the standard requires).
  /S /GTS_PDFA1                   % Must be so (the standard requires).
  /DestOutputProfile {icc_PDFA}            % Must be so (see above).
  /OutputConditionIdentifier (CGATS TR001)      % Customize
>> /PUT pdfmark
[{Catalog} <</OutputIntents [ {OutputIntent_PDFA} ]>> /PUT pdfmark
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you've found a case which was missed, the PDFACompatibility switch was added long after PDF/A output and as it was a retrofit you may have found a code path which avoids it.

I'd suggest you open a bug report, attach the input file, command line, defs file and anything else needed to reproduce the result.

Comment: Quick Q. I have two postscript files. One generated with a TOC and the other without, from Word. I ran
'gswin64 -dPDFA -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=out.pdf file.ps'
The one without TOC generates PDF/A and the other generates PDF/A. Is this a bug? MSWord, using its inbuilt PDF convertor does save both doc versions as PDF/A compliant files. Just want to confirm that this is abnormal behaviour on the part of Ghostscript and I can file a bug report with the PS files as attachments. Thanks so much for your time!

Comment: Another correction. I intended "the one without TOC generates PDF/A and the other DOESNOT".

Comment: I have raised my first bug report:) by an email to ghost@aladdin.com. I am taking a far reaching guess that you are part of the developer team:). if not here is the link.
https://app.box.com/s/mtun3ryhokjoqe4wd861

Comment: Wow, I don't know where you dug up that address, its seriously old and I suspect no longer works. You should actually go to http://bugs.ghostscript.com where you can raise a bug report and you will be able to attach a specimen file.

Comment: lol....I googled "ghostscript bug report" and I landed up with this as the first result
http://ghostscript.com/doc/5.50/Bug-form.htm
Looked genuine too. nevermind, now I know that the bug is in your custody. Thank you so much for helping out!

Comment: Yes its genuine, but the 5.50 in there is the version number of Ghostscript that the documentation refers to. That's the online documentation archive.... 5.50 was a very long time ago. I'm guessing that the problem is simply that you haven't used the correct switch, it should be "-dPDFACompatibilityPolicy=1" case is important, as is the use of -d not -s.

Comment: Thanks....I got the switch typo fixed. However, how do I get the annotations in the PDF? The TOC hyperlinks no longer work in the PDF/A file. When I convert with Word's convertor, I do get a PDF/A with the hyperlinks active. Can you tell me how to get the annotations and PDF/A blue banner in the resultant file using Ghostscript?

Comment: Well basically, you can't. The annotation dictionaries you are supplying have no Flag entry, the PDF/A specification says "An annotation dictionary shall contain the F key. The F key’s Print flag bit shall be set to 1 and its Hidden, Invisible and NoView flag bits shall be set to 0." So the requirement is fundamentally incompatible with your PostScript. An ugly hack would be to override the definition of pdfmark and add a /F entry to the dictionary if one is not present, or OR an existing value with 2. Presumably Word's generator is adding the flag.

Comment: BY the way, the 'blue banner' is almost totally meaningless. It means Acrobat has detected the 'PDF/A' flag in the PDF file, it says nothing about its actual compliance with the spec. The command line and configuration you are using will not produce valid PDF/A files, though they will contain the PDF/A flag, so you get the 'blue banner'.